# What can I use instead of Context Menu in android?

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu, android-library

I want to show some options when clicking a button. I use context menu now. But the context menu showing below Android 3 is not good with the current app design. I want to either change the style of the context menu or use some other controls or replace the context menu with something else. What can I do to make my app design more beautiful? Is there any material design library with material context menu?

Comment: look into [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)

Comment: Thanks @Blackbelt , but ListPopupWindow starts at API 11 :( I want to support from API 9.

Comment: use dialog with list view

Comment: it is also in the support library. Look for it

Comment: `I want to support from API 9` API Level **9** is **dead**. Consider supporting API Level **8** (still listed in the [DashBoard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PopupWindow` which starts from `API level 1`.

In `PopupWindow` you can actually design something with XML Layout file.
You can include anything (TextView,Button,ImageView,...) Like : 
PopUp Window XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="#89000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/idClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="PopUp Window Title"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Item One / Option One"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Item Two / Option Two"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="..."
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/idOpen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And you can Pop It Up in Activity like :

```
package com.example.popup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button open;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View popUpView;
    PopupWindow popupWindow;
    Button close;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        open = (Button)findViewById(R.id.idOpen);
        open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(open);
            }
        });

        inflater =(LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        popUpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window,null);
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popUpView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        close = (Button)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.idClose);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

HOPE THIS WILL HELP, HAPPY CODING :)